# Split.io - How to get treatment without needing to render a component/HOC

Tags: reactjs, feature-flags

I'm working on an application where I need to send a data to the backend from the form, where one of the parameter I need to send a Boolean value. If the email has some @domainexample.com or others, I want this parameter to be true, otherwise it will be false.

But this logic will be done using feature flags, using ***SPLIT.IO*** and React.

According to the documentation, we need to call a SplintTreatments component and the response responder will be in as a child.

However, in my case I don't need to render a component just to get this Boolean.

I would like to now if its possible to get this value without having to call a component, I just want to use something similar to fetch for example.

It is possible? How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do that.

You can just call a hook called useClient from splitio-react, like that.

```
import { useClient } from '@splitsoftware/splitio-react';
```

Then you create a constant to refer useClient like that.

```
const splitClient = useClient();
```

Then, just make a call passing the name of the split on the first parameter, and on the second one pass the objetct. Example bellow:

```
const splitResponse = splitClient?.getTreatmentWithConfig('name_of_split', {
    check_email: 'somevalue@email.com',
  });
```

I hope I helped someone :)

Comment: this all still requires a component to function and doesn't answer the original question. Hooks can only be called from React function components (or other hooks) and `useClient` is a hook.